# Quickbooks Online - Profit Loss Statement Not Showing Certain Income from Paypal Sales Receipt Transactions that are a Repair Service

Tags: quickbooks-online

My current profit loss statement is for 1 month only so I can test this issue. Currently my income is from eBay when I sell goods and I also do repair services on the side. My customers pay me via paypal which gets mixed with all the ebay sales too. As you can see it shows eBay Sales:

[image]

As for this new transaction from the banking tab. It is set as default as "eBay Sales", but it should really be Repair Services.

[image]

Clicking into details of that transaction, I change the product/service to "repair services". If you notice there is no greyed out category next to it.

[image]

After adding this transaction, it doesn't show up on my profit and loss statement. But if I left it as eBay Sales, it will show up. Why and how can this be fixed to have it show up on the profit loss statement? The category does show up if I add it from a non-paypal account like a bank account when a customer pays me via check.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the Profit and Loss report so you can see which accounts make up the Profit and Loss statement.  There you will see the eBay account. Now add the PayPal account in the same general location. Be sure to save the Report and then run it.

As you add accounts for your business, you need to do this each time as it not automatic.

Comment: thanks @john . I figured it out. Any idea to the question in my answer?

Comment: You need to check the account type for each account (Bank, Income, Expense, Asset, Liability, and so on) and make sure the account has the correct type. as different account types have different attributes. For example a Bank Account cannot have expense account attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why this was such an issue is because I was getting confused with product/service and chart of accounts. It was named the same. To solve this problem name it different. Now I have "Repair Related" vs "Repair Services" for chart of accounts.

And the reason for it now showing up in the P&L is because under your product/service you need to select Income Account and set it to the chart of account, in my case it was "Repair Services"

[image]

I'm not sure why it was set to Paypal Bank as Income Account. Anyone know why and what does this do?